# Electron app: npm start gives "Unknown system error -8" on Mac

Tags: node.js, electron

I have an Electron app that runs correctly on Linux and Windows, though I'm trying to run it on a MacOS VM and it's consistently throwing an error on npm start.

```
> NoRA@0.0.1 start
> electron .

node:internal/child_process:421
    throw errnoException(err, 'spawn');
    ^

Error: spawn Unknown system error -8
    at ChildProcess.spawn (node:internal/child_process:421:11)
    at Object.spawn (node:child_process:761:9)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/electron-test/node_modules/electron/cli.js:7:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  errno: -8,
  code: 'Unknown system error -8',
  syscall: 'spawn'
}

Node.js v20.11.1
```

This is an internal error on the node_modules/electron/cli.js in this line:

```
const child = proc.spawn(electron, process.argv.slice(2), { stdio: 'inherit', windowsHide: false });
```

But the error itself is not descriptive of what's going on or what can I fix.

This is a clean installation of nodejs and did npm install.

Comment: Sounds like something you'll want to form a really good [mcve] for, so you can report this over on the [Electron issue tracker](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues)